Jinja2 apply regex_replace when setting variable and perform lookup against json file
I have a json file that includes node IDs along with other data, and another file that includes node IDs and node names. The requirement is to extract the node ID from a longer string, and then do a lookup for the node name within the other json file.
psuoutput.json
  "result": [
    {
      "env": {
        "data": {
          "id": "chassis-5/node-8/psu/psuA",
          "status": "ok",
        }
      }
    },

chassisinv.json
  "result": [
    {
      "chassis": {
        "data": {
          "id": "8",
          "name": "ecuserver",
        }
      }
    },

I can extract the node ID and have an idea of the json_query required to retrieve the node name, however, I cannot make everything work.
    - name: Load inv
      set_fact:
        chassisinv: "{{ lookup('file', 'chassisinv.json') }}"

    - name: Extract data
      vars:
        input: "{{ lookup('file',psuoutput.json) | from_json }}"
      set_fact:
        csv_content: |
          {% for server in input.result %}
          {% set nodeid = server.env.data.id | regex_replace('.*node-([^\/]*).*', '\1') %}
          {% set nodename = {{ chassisinv | from_json | json_query(".result[] | select (.chassis.data.id=="{{ nodeid }}").chassis.data.name") }}
          {{ nodeid }},{{ nodename }},{{ server.env.data.status }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost

Jinja2 doesn't seem to apply the regex_replace while setting nodeid, so {{ nodeid }} results in an empty variable and the json_query errors as it cannot run using empty lookup data.
I'm also not sure this is the optimal way to decode data (name), taking as input a regexp-manipulated json field (id), looking for it within another json file.
Would you be able to assist, please?

Can't you simply use jq in combination w some shell magic?

Your example data is not valid json, your jinja2 expression is firing a templating error. This is not a [mre]

With valid JSON structures a minimal example playbook
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    input:
      result: [
        {
          "env": {
            "data": {
              "id": "chassis-5/node-8/psu/psuA",
              "status": "ok",
            }
          }
        }
      ]

    chassisinv:
      result: [
        {
          "chassis": {
            "data": {
              "id": "8",
              "name": "eight",
            }
          }
        }
      ]

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
        {% for i in input.result %}
        {% set nodeid = (i.env.data.id | split('/') )[1] | split('-') | last %}
        {% set nodename = (chassisinv.result | selectattr("chassis.data.id", 'match', nodeid) | first ).chassis.data.name %}
        {{ nodeid }}, {{ nodename }}, {{ i.env.data.status }}
        {% endfor %}

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    8, eight, ok

Thanks To

Ansible: How to filter a list by its attributes?

